# awaiting the initialisation of a scoped property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await

In a .net core application, I have an ISessionService (it just contains various reusable properties, like the current "Company" based on what the currently URL is.

It is defined in startup like this:

```
services.AddScoped<ISessionService, SessionService>();
```

SessionService has a property that is .Company.  But in .Company a call is made to the database which, because it's a property, can't be awaited.  So it currently looks like

```
public ICompany Company => dbContext.GetCompany(host).Result
```

The .Result is causing application hangs under heavy load.  I could put this in the constructor of SessionService, but that just moves the .Result from the property to the constructor and causes the same problem.

Is there a way, through the initialisation of SessionService perhaps, to initialise in an async way without having to do any synchronous calls like .Result?

Comment: Change it to "public Task Company -> dbContext.GetCompany(host)" then await it in your consuming code... Although this sounds like something you'd want to do in middleware then cache rather than hit the database every time its requested

Comment: @Milney How would you go about doing it in a middleware cache?

Comment: Well it sounds like you have some sort of multi-tenant system. In this case the definition of which 'company' you are accessing is kind of a form of Authorization (or atleast Routing) which are both cross-cutting concerns. You can take a look at https://michael-mckenna.com/multi-tenant-asp-dot-net-core-application-tenant-resolution for a basic example or like the code from SAASKit for a richer one https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit. And you'll probably want to use like the in-memory cache or Redis or something to avoid hitting database every single time you do the mapping

Comment: If thats overkill for your scenario, maybe you have just few 'companies' just do the database quer(y)(ies) on startup and store in the standard cache https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0 then your SessionService can just take it out of that instead of hitting the database

Comment: Generally, I would recommend using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of using `.Result` in order to avoid wrapped exceptions. Will not solve the issue though. BR

Answer (score 1):

Do not introduce any synchronous blocking of asynchronous code. You'll hurt the performance and scalability of your application.

What you want should be done with a combination of a middleware and a feature.

Your middleware should add that information to the [collection of features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.features).

I can see [how they are used in the codebase](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features/IFeatureCollection.cs,a1176f964a1c46f8,references).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a property, which claims, it needs some time until the Result is there, it should be of type `Task<ICompany>`:

```
public Task<ICompany> Company => dbContext.GetCompany(host);
```

Having said that, I am showing now an option, which can initialize a class the async way.

Provide an async initialization method:

```
public class SessionService
{
    public string Company { get; private set; }

    //Inject DbContext via CTOR

    public Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        //Use DbContext, probably think about caching
        Company = "Async Company";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then create a [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) which calls the `InitializeAsync` method*:

```
public class InitializationMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly SessionService _sessionService;

    public InitializationMiddleware(SessionService sessionService)
    {
        _sessionService = sessionService;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        await _sessionService.InitializeAsync();
        await next(context);
    }
}
```

Register everything into the ServiceCollection:

```
services.AddScoped<InitializationMiddleware>();
services.AddScoped<SessionService>();
```

Finaly use the middleware (probably after `app.UseAuthorization();`):

```
app.UseMiddleware<InitializationMiddleware>();
```

<sub>* As an alternative, you can make `SessionService` an `IMiddleware` itself, and initialize it in `InvokeAsync`. Then you would use `app.UseMiddleware<SessionService>();`</sub>